# Why does this JavaScript closure array retain the old values

Tags: javascript, arrays, arguments, closures

I came across an interesting situation with java-script closure and arrays.
I am not sure which part of the javascript is causing the caching of the arguments array.

```js
var SLICE = Array.prototype.slice;

  var attach = function(method) {
    var args = SLICE.call(arguments, 1);
    return function() {
      args = args.concat(SLICE.call(arguments, 0));
      method.apply(null, args);
    };
  };

  function foo(param1, param2, param3) {
    console.log(param1, param2, param3);
  };

  var bar = attach(foo, 1, 2);
  bar(3);
  bar(4);
```

The output of the above code is

```
1 2 3
1 2 3
```

instead of

```
1 2 3
1 2 4
```

The correct output is obtained if the code is changed to

```js
var SLICE = Array.prototype.slice;

  var attach = function(method) {
    var args = SLICE.call(arguments, 1);
    return function() {
      method.apply(null, args.concat(SLICE.call(arguments, 0)));
    };
  };

  function foo(param1, param2, param3) {
    console.log(param1, param2, param3);
  };

  var bar = attach(foo, 1, 2);
  bar(3);
  bar(4);
```

The output is

```
1 2 3
1 2 4
```

I would like to understand, which property of java script is the reason behind this happening?

EDIT:
THE CODE HAS BEEN EDITED TO REMOVE THE PUSH, AND EXPLAIN BETTER THE SCENERIO

Comment: Because `push` mutates the `args`.

Comment: @Bergi, removed the push, to better explain the scenario  that is happening

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `foo` function only accepts three arguments,

```
function foo(param1, param2, param3) {
```

and it's only ever being sent three

```
method(args[0], args[1], args[2]);
```

yet, `push()` pushes to the array, so when you have `[1,2,3,4]` only the three first are sent, not the fourth.

Had the function accepted four arguments

```js
var SLICE = Array.prototype.slice;

var attach = function(method) {
    var args = SLICE.call(arguments, 1);

    return function() {
        for (var key in arguments) {
            args.push(arguments[key]);
        }
        method(args[0], args[1], args[2], args[3]);
    };
};

function foo(param1, param2, param3, param4) {
    console.log(param1, param2, param3, param4);
};

var bar = attach(foo, 1, 2);
bar(3);
bar(4);
```

You'd be getting `1 2 3 4` in the console.

In other words, this has nothing to do with caching, or the values not being added, it's just the function that doesn't accept enough arguments as new values are pushed to the array.

The better approach would be functions that accepts any number of arguments

```js
var SLICE = Array.prototype.slice;

var attach = function(method) {
    var args = SLICE.call(arguments, 1);

    return function() {
        args = args.concat( SLICE.call(arguments) );
        method.apply(null, args)
    };
};

function foo() {
    console.log(arguments);
};

var bar = attach(foo, 1, 2);
bar(3);
bar(4);
```

the reason the second code snippet in the question doesn't keep adding to the array is because the array is not stored, concat returns a new array, it does not alter the original, so it has to be

```
args = args.concat(array);
```

to store the changes. As you're not storing the changes, everytime the inner function is called, it takes the original array `[1,2]` and adds a single value to it, and then returns it.

Because it's not stored, the first time you call `bar(3)` it takes `[1,2]` and adds `3`, and you end up with `[1,2,3]`.
The next time the function is called, it just does the same thing, takes `[1,2]` and adds 4 etc. and you end up with `[1,2,4]` instead.

Comment: i understand it is because of the way the argument is concated, so, i have edited the code to better explain the scenario. I dont want to change the structure of the foo or the number of parameters being passed to it

Comment: @goku - the reason the second code snippet doesn't keep adding to the array is because the array is not stored, everytime the inner function is called, it takes the original array `[1,2]` and adds a single value to it, and it returns it, it's not stored so the next time the function is called, it just does the same thing, takes `[1,2]` and adds `4` etc.

Comment: thanks a lot for the comment, can you post this as an answer?, i will accept this.

Comment: @goku - sure, I've added that to the answer as well.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to adeneo's answer you can use [Function.prototype.bind()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) to implement your `attach` function:

```
function attach(method, a, b) {
    return method.bind(method, a, b);
}

function foo(param1, param2, param3) {
    console.log(param1, param2, param3);
};

var bar = attach(foo, 1, 2);
bar(3);
bar(4);
//output is 
// 1 2 3
// 1 2 4
```